# How to differentiate the xAxis and yAxis plotbands in Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to toggle the x Axis and y Axis plot bands when the user clicks on plotband legendItem. I know that we can use `#addPlotBandOrLine` and `#removePlotBandOrLine` to toggle the plotbands.

I used the code in `set Visible: function (visible, redraw)` in `highcharts.js`

```
setVisible: function (vis, redraw) {
        var series = this,
        ---

   if(showOrHide == 'show')
    series.chart.axes[0].addPlotBandOrLine(series.userOptions);
   if(showOrHide == 'hide')
    series.chart.axes[0].removePlotBandOrLine(series.userOptions.id);
}
```

If I use this I can toggle only the x Axis plot band. Here I'm unable to differentiate the x Axis and y Axis plot bands. Please help me to differentiate the axis.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you intriduce your full example, as live demo?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it which axis to look at. See [this](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis) API doc.

Comment: Yeah, but I'm unable to find it

Comment: You need to tell it like this: `series.chart.yAxes[0].addPlotBandOrLine(series.userOptions);`